# How to Authenticate a user by recovering a token on their behalf - Azure AD

Tags: authentication, automation, azure-active-directory

My I am trying to deploy azure AD to my application because I want to expose some of my APIs to users but I need to make sure only people that are authorized can use the resource.

I have never worked with azure AD before and I am a little lost in all the documentation.

What I need is to be able to recover a token on behalf of the user in order to authenticate them. The application does not have any webpages and I do not want to introduce any. I want to be able to grab the token, authenticate the user, and then release the resource. I expect that the endpoint will be accessed through python, java or postman.

Example of basic flow:

1. call security function/api in app
2. validate user cred (or any other type of validation)
3. return token if authenticated
4. validate token and return response
   5.authentication allows user to call apis

I have just explored the authorization code pattern that azure AD offers but this requires an interactive step from what I was able to test so its no good.

I would like to be able to do something like the example flow

In case my question hasn't clued you in I am very new to this so any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: `this requires an interactive step from what I was able to test so its no good.` then your requirement can't be realized I'm afraid..  You said `only people with access can use the resource` so you have  to let users sign in to pass the authentication so that AAD can help you generate an access token on behalf of the user(containing user inforamtion)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I edited the post to be a bit more specific, authorization code is just 1 flow offered by azure AD there are other flows and patterns but there is a lot of documentation to go through. 

To your knowledge is there a way we can authenticate without a webpage? like in a code block for example even if user provides username and password?

Comment: You can always authenticate using client credentials flow which is designed solely for app to app communication. Use it wisely :P

Comment: ROPC flow can allow you to hard code username/password in the code but it's not designed for your scenario. In your scenario, you need to allow specific users to access specific resource, it have to have a webpage to let users sign in. I'm afraid what you want maybe like send an http request along with the username/password, even it's possible to do it, it's not recommended.... you may need to redesign your app... By the way client credentials flow mentioned by Gopal really doesn't need to let users sign in, but it also makes your API who sends the request to your API.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **@Gopal** you can make use of client credentials flow that does not require user interaction to call an API.

You just need to enter Azure AD client application’s ID, Secret, scope to generate the access token and use that access token to call the API via Postman or in your code.

I created one  [Asp.net](http://Asp.net)  core API in VS studio and used Azure Ad authentication to call the API.

[image]

*I tried accessing this API via Postman App with different flows that you can try :-*

**Client Credentials flow:-**

```http
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials  
client_id:<appID>  
client_secret:<secret>  
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

[image]

**Results :-**

[image]

API can be accessed by the Access token generated by the client app with its secret and scope.

Alternatively, you can make use of Implicit flow which will ask for user credentials via browser.

**Implicit flow :-**

Here, Your log in page pops up while asking for access token and you need to enter user credentials to get access token and fetch API.
Get the token and hit the token to fetch the API like below :-

[image]

Browser Pop up:-

[image]

Access Token:-

[image]

Now, copy our API URL from browser and try to access the API :-

**Results :-**

[image]

You can find the code samples below :-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api