# How to call GenerateToken REST API with 2FA enabled microsoft Azure account

Tags: azure, rest, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, two-factor-authentication

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMmAX.png)

```
API POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
```

MY Senerio :

**Step1:** I need to login to my Microsoft 2FA enabled account through rest API backend service and get the access token.

**Step2:**
With that access token need to hit powerbi account API to get embedded token.

**Issue:**
This process has to be fully REST API with NO prompt to take code from users.
When 2FA is enabled in Microsoft account .This API doesn't work. It shows this error

```json
"error": "interaction_required",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Trace ID: 05451564-7c99-454f-9f1c-85b5d0ac6a00 Correlation ID: 026670ad-9c04-46d8-828b-0c1435938e90 Timestamp: 2023-11-05 14:11:35Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50076
    ]
```

But by disable 2FA it works well. So, how can I call this API by enabling 2FA ?

Comment: Can you share your overall scenario, what are you trying to do/achieve? Usually there are three alternatives: Use a connector that supports OAuth, using PAT (Personal Access Token), registering an app in Azure then using App Authentication...

Comment: I need the azure access token  to get embedded token from powerbi but due to 2FA enabled in azure account  couldn't get the token. I followed the authorization code approach and grant type 'client credentials' approaches. got the token but still when hit powerbi with that token it dont work. and showed 'PowerBIEntityNotFound'  where as in my powerbi account reports, dataset and workspaces all are available and correct parameters are given.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving an "interaction_required" error when calling an API with 2FA-enabled Microsoft accounts, it means that the application is trying to perform a non-interactive authentication while the account is configured for multi-factor authentication (MFA).

In such cases, you typically need to use a different authentication method, such as a certificate or client secret or Device code flow, which doesn't rely on user interaction for MFA.

**Using client secret**

Here's how I modified my application to use a client secret for authentication, which  work is Working fine with 2FA-enabled accounts

```cs
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
            string tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID";
            string clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"; // Replace with your client secret
            string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
            string apiScope = "https://api.example.com/.default"; // Replace with your API scope
            string apiEndpoint = "https://api.example.com/generateToken"; // Replace with your API endpoint
    
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                .Build();
    
            string[] scopes = new string[] { apiScope };
    
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiEndpoint, null);
    
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("API call successful.");
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"API call failed with status code {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Result**
[image]

**Device code flow**

The device code flow is a two-step authentication flow. In the first step, the user opens a web browser and navigates to a specific URL. They are then prompted to enter a device code that is displayed on the application. Once the user has entered the device code, they are granted access to the application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please look  into this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011264/how-to-authenticate-a-user-by-recovering-a-token-on-their-behalf-azure-ad) ,You can make use of Implicit Flow for authenticating with User that has MFA enabled